# What is the purpose of using the arrow symbol(->) at the start of the method?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

While going through a tutorial, I came across the following code and didn't understand why the arrow symbol was used at the start of the method

I tried searching about the arrow operator but it looks like it has many uses, and I couldn't find an answer to my question.

```
someButton.setOnClickListener { view -> 
    someMethod()
}
```

I did not understand why 'view ->' is used. I know I'm a beginner and this question might be too silly to ask, but I can't find an answer anywhere on the internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a part of Kotlin syntax.
`view -> someMethod()` is [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions). The part before the arrow defines the function arguments, and the part after the arrow is the function body.

[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter) you can read about your case (passing lambda as the last parameter).

---

If you are a beginner, I would suggest you to learn some basic staff about this things. In this order: Anonymous class -> Functional interface -> Functions.

Comment: (The braces are also a necessary part of the lambda syntax, aren't they?  And the parameters and arrow aren't needed for a zero-parameter lambda, or a one-parameter lambda with `it`.)

Comment: That's right. You can get all this information from the official documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html